# custom config module validation with joi

Tags: nestjs, joi

So I followed the guide on how to create a configuration for my Nest app

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration

and due to the fact I have many configuration parts I wanted to split the parts into multiple configuration services. So my **app.module.ts** imports a custom config module

```
@Module({
  imports: [CustomConfigModule]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

This custom config module (**config.module.ts**) bundles all the config services and loads the Nest config module

```
@Module({
  imports: [ConfigModule.forRoot()],
  providers: [ServerConfigService],
  exports: [ServerConfigService],
})
export class CustomConfigModule {}
```

Lastly I have a simple config service **server.config.service.ts** which returns the port the application is running on

```
@Injectable()
export class ServerConfigService {
  constructor(private readonly configService: ConfigService) {}

  public get port(): number {
    return this.configService.get<number>('SERVER_PORT');
  }
}
```

I would like to validate those services on application startup. The docs explain how to setup a validationschema for the configuration module

https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/configuration#schema-validation

How can I use that for my service validation when using a custom config module?
Do I have to call joi in each service constructor and validate the properties there?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe in your `ConfigModule.forRoot()` you can set the validation schema and tell Nest to run the validations on start up instead of having to add it to each custom config service. The docs show something like:

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({
      validationSchema: Joi.object({
        NODE_ENV: Joi.string()
          .valid('development', 'production', 'test', 'provision')
          .default('development'),
        PORT: Joi.number().default(3000),
      }),
      validationOptions: {
        allowUnknown: false,
        abortEarly: true,
      },
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Which would run validations on `NODE_ENV` and `PORT`. You could of course extend it out to more validations overall. And then you could just have one `ConfigModule` that has smaller config services that split each segment up so all validations are run on startup and only what you need is available in each module's context.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for your reply. I was looking for a way to have my joi validation within the **server.config.service.ts** and another joi validation within **database.config.service.ts**. How would you do it? Just call it in the constructor of each service? I think this would be a cleaner approach because each config could validate itself and the custom config module doesn't have to know about all those fields flying around...

Comment: If you want separate validations, you'll need a Joi schema for each validation and you'll need to run the validation in the constructor (or a method called from the constructor) of each service. Honestly, as validation can be pretty heavy, I would say getting it out of the way at start up, all in the same place, is preferable just because it keeps everything together. That's my two cents, though